# Meteor Store input in a Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, collections

I'm new in meteor js programming and my intent is collect input from a form of radio button for multiple answer inside a collection Answers.
The problem now is that if I click on the submit button I see the answers optvalue in the Url tab but if I open the console in Chrome and digit Answers.find().fetch() there are not items inside the collection.

My project view is :

```
-project
--client
------main.js
------main.html
------main.css
--imports
---api
------answers.js
---ui
------body.js
------body.html
--server
------main.js
```

client/main.js

```
import '../imports/api/answers.js';
import '../imports/ui/body.js';
```

imports/api/answer.js

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Answers = new Mongo.Collection('answers');

Answers.allow({
    insert(){return false;},
    update(){return false;},
    remove(){return false;},
});

Answers.deny({
    insert(){return true;},
    update(){return true;},
    remove(){return true;},
});
```

imports/ui/body.html

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Questionnaire</h1>
    </header>
    {{> questionnaire}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="questionnaire">
    <form> 
        {{#each questions}}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>{{qtitle}}</legend>
            <p>{{qtext}}</p>
            {{#each options}}
                <p><input type="radio" name="{{this.optqgroup}}" value="{{this.optvalue}}" required>  {{this.optxt}}</p>
            {{/each}}
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        {{/each}}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit your answers">
  </form>
</template>
```

imports/ui/body.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './body.html';

Template.questionnaire.events({
    'submit form': function(event,template) {
        questions.forEach(function(question) { 
            let selected = event.target[question.optgroup].value;
            Meteor.call('insertAnswer', selected, (error)=> {
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        });
    }
});


Template.body.helpers({
questions : [
  { 
    qtitle: "1. Title Q1", 
    qtext: "Text Q1", 
    options:[
        {optgroup:"q1", 
         optvalue: "q1_opt1", 
         opttxt: "Option 1"},
        {optgroup:"q1", 
         optvalue: "q1_opt2", 
         opttxt: "Option 2"}]},
    {
    qtitle: "2. Title Q2", 
    qtext: "Text Q2",
    options:[
        {optgroup:"q2", 
         optvalue: "q2_opt1", 
         opttxt: "Option 1"},
        {optgroup:"q2", 
         optvalue: "q2_opt2", 
         opttxt: "Option 2"},]}]});
```

server/main.js

```
import '../imports/api/answers.js';


Meteor.methods({
    insertAnswer(selected){
        Answers.insert({
                selected:selected
        });
    }
});
```

Can you please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: (a) have you removed the `autopublish` package and if so (b) where are your publication and corresponding subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first things first.. Inside your submit event you need to prevent the default form submission action.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

otherwise your browser will just execute a post request to the current URL with the form data as the body of the request and cause the page to seemingly refresh.

Something else to consider is that you can't access your template helpers as variables inside your template events. They'll only be available inside your template's mustache tags like `{{questions}}`. Also helpers need to be functions. If you need to access your questions array from both your template events and your template helper, you could declare it as a variable inside the same file as the template helper/event code but not within either and then use it in your events or return it from a helper.

```
const questions = [
    {
        qtitle: '1. Title Q1',
        qtext: 'Text Q1',
        options: [{
                optgroup: 'q1',
                optvalue: 'q1_opt1',
                opttxt: 'Option 1'
            },
            {
                optgroup: 'q1',
                optvalue: 'q1_opt2',
                opttxt: 'Option 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        qtitle: '2. Title Q2',
        qtext: 'Text Q2',
        options: [{
                optgroup: 'q2',
                optvalue: 'q2_opt1',
                opttxt: 'Option 1'
            },
            {
                optgroup: 'q2',
                optvalue: 'q2_opt2',
                opttxt: 'Option 2'
            }
        ]
    }
];

Template.questionnaire.events({
    'submit form': function(event,template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        questions.forEach(function(question) { 
            let selected = event.target[question.optgroup].value;
            Meteor.call('insertAnswer', selected, (error)=> {
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        });
    }
});

Template.body.helpers({
    questions() {
        return questions;
    }
});
```